# Getting "session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114" in selenium Javascript

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting this error on running my test cases with selenium-webdriver.

```
[13:18:54] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.188 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'WIN-FOURTEEN', ip: '172.30.176.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.4.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0029A813+48355]
        (No symbol) [0x0022C4B1]
        (No symbol) [0x00135358]
        (No symbol) [0x001561AC]
        (No symbol) [0x00151EF3]
        (No symbol) [0x00150579]
        (No symbol) [0x00180C55]
        (No symbol) [0x0018093C]
        (No symbol) [0x0017A536]
        (No symbol) [0x001582DC]
        (No symbol) [0x001593DD]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x004FAABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0053A78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0053456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x003251E0+616112]
        (No symbol) [0x00235F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x00232328]
        (No symbol) [0x0023240B]
        (No symbol) [0x00224FF7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76DEFCC9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x777C7B1E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x777C7AEE+238]
        (No symbol) [0x00000000]
```

I suppose the issue is occurring due to version mismatch between selenium-webdriver and chromeDriver but I am unable to figure out the solution.

These are my versions of some relevant dependencies:

```
{
  "webdriver-manager": "^12.1.2"
  "selenium-standalone": "^7.1.0"
  "selenium-webdriver": "^4.12.0"
}
```

snippet from my testing script

```
yarn selenium-standalone install 
yarn selenium-standalone  start 2>/dev/null &
while ! nc -z 127.0.0.1 4444; do sleep 3; done
node_modules/.bin/protractor my-tests/conf.js
```

Comment: `Build info: version: '3.141.59'` From the error, it seems like the selenium being used is very old.